# Where are my copied files?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive

I tried to copy all the files from my USB drive using the "dd"  command. Output shows success, equal in and out# of  records,  and less total GB available on HDD where I saved them to, but files are nowhere to be found. Ubuntu os.

```
dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/home/directory/foldername
```

where `sdx` = `sdb` = files to copy from USB; `of` =destination on hdd. `directory` = comp name; I created folder to put image in.

I mounted usb as "read-only".

I found my files, the image. How can I tell if it is corrupt?

Comment: cp (or rsync) should be used unless you need a dd specific feature, what exact command did you use?

Comment: There is not enough info in the question. Tell us the `dd` command that you used. And/or do you know the names of the files?

Comment: @KM no. /home/comp-name/foldername, but folder is empty.

Comment: I mounted USB as "read-only". I think that's why not finding, though output said success

Comment: @km Its correct what I wrote above. It was on the desktop. When I right-clicked inside desktop directory, it showed "/home/comp-name/Desktop". I replaced "desktop" with a folder name for the folder I put there. If I change foldername to "Desktop", you are saying that won't work b/c Desktop is a directory? Maybe I need to write "/home/comp-name/Desktop/foldername...? I could also just use "of=/sda"?

Comment: ...correction: when I clicked on the destination  "folder" inside desktop directory, it said "/home/comp/Desktop".

Comment: If you use `of=/dev/sda` (as mentioned in a previous comment), you would overwrite your machine's filesystem with that of the USB drive. Don't do that. It would lead to not being able to boot, and to loss of data.  You seem to not know the difference between a **device file** and a **file on a device**.

Comment: @km That is a folder I created before using dd. She'll says: "rw,r,r" "1 root root 8019509248 Aug 11 10:49 /home/comp-name/foldername"

Comment: @km when I run "ls -l" it seems to show it as file. It shows other files I can't find too.

Comment: @ka The file only shows in shell, apparently under downloads. But it is not in downloads, just like the other missing files.

Comment: @ka I found it as a hidden file in nano. I had "hidden files" checked in the directories, but it didn't show there. Nano says it's reading the file, but no output yet.

Comment: I found the file as a hidden file. There is no .iso or .img anywhere in the directories. I just want to move it off hdd to a new flash drive.

Comment: I re-did it, this time adding the desktop directory before adding a filename. "dd if=/dev/sdb bs=16M of=/home/whoami/Desktop/newfilename". Now I have an 8 GB encrypted file on the desktop.

Comment: It's not encrypted; it's an image file of the USB stick. If you mounted the filesystem and then copied the device you could easily have a file containing corrupted data. If you don't understand what Kusalananda and I are telling you then please ask for an explanation.

Comment: @roaima Thanks. Why might it have corrupt data? Since we are on the topic ..with the "image", I get the feeling I can not access those files the same way I would if I had copied and pasted, yes? I imagine I would have to do something with the image first .

Comment: @roaima Are you saying b/c I used "sdb" instead of "sdb1", there is a greater risk for corrupt data? Either way, how can I tell if the new image is corrupted? Thx.

Comment: You are copying a USB image, not the files on the USB. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: You've got the filesystem mounted *and* you're copying the live filesystem from the raw device. This is a really bad idea because the filesystem as written on the USB itself can be changed while you're still copying it, meaning you end up with an inconsistent view of the filesystem, which can lead to corruption in the copied image. Simple answer: stop copying the USB image and instead copy the files on the USB.

Comment: The question is now unclear. It asks "How can I find..." in the title, then says "I found them". Then it goes on to ask _a new question_. I'm closing this question as unclear.

Comment: @roaima Yes, I know the difference; I want the usb image in case I need to put the image back on the usb should the usb get corrupted when trying to recover deleted and/or stolen files. So how would you recommend copying the image? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have copied an image of your USB stick. Instead, just copy the files:

```
cp -a /media/... ~/foldername  # Replace "..." with the rest of the path to the mounted USB stick
```

If you're not sure where your system has mounted the USB stick you can find out with either of these commands

```
df -h                          # List all the mounted filesystems; look for the one you want

mount | awk '/sdx/ {print $4}' # List of mounted filesystems, match "sdx", print mountpoint
```

I would strongly recommend that until become more familiar with UNIX/Linux systems you forget you have ever heard of the `dd` command. Really. (Why? Because there are very few situations where it's actually needed. Often for a raw copy `cat` is actually faster - and certainly no slower. And here, `cp` is the correct command to use.)

Comment: I've used the dd command before, didn't have a problem.

Comment: @hddfsck777 You may well have, but to copy the _files_ on a USB device, you would not use `dd` to make a dump of the device drive itself.

Comment: @hddfsck777: Incidentally, what you achieved with `dd` could also be achieved with `cp`: `cp /dev/sdx /home/directory/foldername`

Answer (score -2):

Must use correct path to get the image accessible after it is copied over. /home/John/Desktop/anyfilename worked. However, file seems to be encrypted (101010). If I need to transfer the image back to flash drive, should the original flash drive image get damaged, don't know if the encryption will be an issue. Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. It's not an encrypted file. It's an image of your USB stick.

Comment: @kusa well, when it copied over to the hdd, the file was locked, and had 1's and 0's on 'face' of the file as it sat in desktop folder (I did not try to open the file), I thought that stood for encryption.

Comment: I'm assuming that icon just meant "binary file", which would be correct. I don't know what you mean by "locked". If you had wanted to copy the files from the USB stick, you would have mounted it and copied them with `cp` as ordinary files.

Comment: @kusa Well, I need to use a data recovery tool and was told to copy by blocks. Will a binary file open with root password?

Comment: Your question never mentions anything  about data recovery. It say "I want to copy all files". The image file that you created with `dd` is not locked or encrypted and I don't know where you got that idea from. I still don't know what it is you're actually wanting to do.

Comment: @kusa I want an identical backup to the flash drive files, bit by bit. If I use a recovery tool on the original flash drive, and it gets damaged, I want a replica backup I can put back on it and use a different recovery tool and try again. Originally, when I copied the files, they were nowhere to be found ony comp, so that's where the original question originates from. After copying them again with a different path name, I got the backup to my desktop. Thx.

Comment: @kusa At this point, I need to know if the backup I just created is corrupt or not. Roaimo seems to think it might. How can I tell? Thx.

Comment: If not for the sake of politeness, then for the sake of successfully pinging me, use my full name in comments.  Your question is not telling us what you'd want to do. I suggest that you edit it to describe what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @kusalananda Sure. I thought admin did not want changes to questions after comments posted, only additional points there. I'll edit it. Thx.